# Hit area of the button changed in silverlight after some functions

Tags: silverlight

Hi I am working on one project on one page there are many controls like hyperlinkbutton, buttons, borders all these bounded by viewbox. when page loads all the buttons shows hand cursor but if i mouse over any other buttons this first buttons do not show any hand cursor or do not take any mouse event. But I abserved one strange thing here when i make full screen in browser buttons will show hand cursor when i disable the full screen view I abserved hit area of the button is above one 2cm from the respective buttons.
I browsed many sites I could not get the answer.
among them I pasted one link here so that you can understand well
http://forums.silverlight.net/t/44026.aspx
So can any one help me help me to resolve this? Please Help me.

Comment: You'll have to share code for us to diagnose